# Mapping a secondary domain to a subdirectory using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, dns, subdirectory

I am looking to map a secondary domain to a subfolder on my document root.

For example, if requests to the domain `www.example.com` map to my DocumentToot, then requests to `www.exampletwo.com` go to `/sites/files/`.

I am unable to accomplish a redirect from `www.exampletwo.com/index.html` to `www.exampletwo.com/sites/files/index.html` while making the URL still display `www.exampletwo.com/index.html`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?exampletwo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /sites/files/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hmm, still no dice. I tried the above and tested it by visiting exampletwo.com/, but I get 404NotFound because the index page is located in /sites/files/index.html, and it isn't rewriting

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify that the www was to be optional.  The updated regexp should catch either.

Comment: Be sure that the Rewrite Engine is on, otherwise the directives are ignored:
`RewriteEngine on`
[RewriteEngine Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.exampletwo.com/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?exampletwo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.exampletwo.com/sites/files/$1 [L,P]
```

The P flag uses the proxy module, therefore the url is not changed (no redirect) on the client.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't seem to act as I expected. To clarify, when someone visits example.com/, I redirect them to exampletwo.com/sites/files/, but mod_rewrite would rewrite the URL to just display exampletwo.com/.

Comment: Changed. First you need to redirect example to exampletwo, then you need to mask /site/files.