# Bi-directional URL mapping and canonicalization using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-mapping

I'm pretty sure this is partly the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810846/mapping-a-secondary-domain-to-a-subdirectory-using-mod-rewrite), but it's a two-parter with a few extra intricacies.

I recently inherited a site for an organization (we'll call it `theorganization.com`) with [Joomla!](http://www.joomla.org/) installed and someone just went and bought a secondary domain (`anevent.com`) for an event it's hosting with the expectation that we can just "point" it right at the relevant section of our existing site.  Yes, simple "masking" could accomplish this in *one* direction, but I'd like to canonicalize the URL and map it in **both** directions using `mod_rewrite`, *etc.*  (This is *not* an infinite loop: one direction is a 301 redirect; the other is a URL mask.)

I want to host information on the event on our existing Joomla! installation at the section accessible at `theorganization.com/eventname/` and equivocate this with the new domain.  **Note:** Joomla! uses rewrites itself, so there will *not* be a physical directory `eventname` within the directory housing `theorganization.com`.  (Not sure if/how that affects anything here.)

Specifically, I want **all** requests made to either `theorganization.com/eventname` or `anevent.com` (with or without `www` or trailing slash) to serve the content which Joomla! would normally ascribe to `theorganization.com/eventname/` while showing the URL as `www.anevent.com/`.  Of course, all subdirectories and files below these levels should map accordingly as well.

---

After looking through [Apache's `mod_rewrite` docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html), I came up with the attempt below.

**For `theorganization.com`:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# STRIP "www" IF PRESENT (undesired, but necessary for now due to other issues)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.theorganization.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://theorganization.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eventname/?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^http://(www\.)theorganization.com/eventname/?(.*)$ "http://www.anevent.com/$2" [R=301,L] 

# ...
# ... default Joomla! .htaccess code here ...
```

After much trial, I found that I'd forgotten Joomla! has its own rewrites in `.htaccess` by default and I had inadvertently overwritten them.  (Thankfully, I [found a replacement](http://www.webmasterworld.com/content_management/4274518.htm).)  But the second (operative) redirect doesn't seem to be taking effect as it should.  What might I be doing wrong?

**For `anevent.com`:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# ADD "www" IF MISSING
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# UNCONDITIONALLY DEFER ALL REQUESTS HERE TO theorganization.com/eventname/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://theorganization.com/eventname/$1 [L]
```

This seems to work pretty well (based on the assumption that I can get the first one to work).  However, the unconditional rule on the last line seems to act as a 301/302 or something similar and loads up `http://theorganization.com/eventname/FOO`.  How can I modify this to achieve "masking" instead, so that users only see `http://www.anevent.com/FOO` in their browser but are still directed to the same content?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, add the following to your .htaccess file in the root of `theorganization.com` site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if its on theorganization.com domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} theorganization\.com$ [NC]
#if the original request has eventname in it
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /eventname/ [NC]
# redirect eventname to anevent.com
RewriteRule ^eventname/(.*)$ http://www.anevent.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**For anevent.com:**

Your rule has a fully qualified URL so it will automatically redirect.
I modified it as below to do a server side rewrite as below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if not internal redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ theorganization.com/eventname/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The paths to each domain are directories named `theorganization.com` and `anevent.com` within the same root.  Could you edit your second example for this case?  Also, what is the function of the `^[A-Z]{3,9}\ ` in your first example?

Comment: @TimParenti changed to match folder structure. `^[A-Z]{3,9}\ ` is to match the HTTP method GET,PUT etc.

Comment: The first one works perfectly; thanks.  But the second one is causing an Internal Server Error.  How can I pinpoint the cause?

Comment: @TimParenti I made an edit to the rule. See if that works. If not check httpd.conf to see where the RewriteLog is located - look for the `RewriteLog /path` directive - and see if it has any clues.

Comment: I think we're closing in on it.  I had to add `../` in front of the substitution in the last line, since that's the actual path I need to travel to get into the other domain.  Now it's just a **400 Bad Request.**  We're on shared hosting, so viewing httpd.conf is out, but the "default configuration" given by the company seems to only specify a few `ErrorDocument` lines.